# Separate Laravel controller for each URL route?

Tags: laravel, lumen

I am building a REST API server (in Lumen, actually, rather than Laravel) with multiple endpoints that allow various operations to be performed on resources such as Users, Accounts, and Products.  For example, here are the routes I have defined for the User resource:

```
GET /v1.0/user
POST /v1.0/user
GET /v1.0/user/{username}
PUT /v1.0/user/{username}
DELETE /v1.0/user/{username}
```

I currently have all of these API routes for a particular resource defined in a single controller.  For example, here are my routes for the User resource:

```
$router->get('/v1.0/user', 'UserController@listAll');
$router->post('/v1.0/user', 'UserController@createUser');
$router->get('/v1.0/user/{username}', 'UserController@getUser');
$router->put('/v1.0/user/{username}', 'UserController@updateUser');
$router->delete('/v1.0/user/{username}', 'UserController@deleteUser');
```

Some of the controller logic is getting pretty complex, and I am now finding that my controller files are getting really, really long.  I am now thinking that I should use a separate controller file for each route, to make the code more maintainable.

My question is whether there is any idiom or convention I should follow with regard to file/folder naming or structure.  Should I create a subfolder under Controllers for each resource (ex: Controllers/User/UserCreateController.php)?  Or is this entirely a matter of personal choice?

Comment: what you are doing in your controller method, that is making it complex, you do not need validation, queries like stuffs in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Single Action Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#single-action-controllers) which take only the `__invoke()` method and can handle one single route.

By the way, what I see usually is that when a controller logic is getting complex, is time to refactor and move that complexity outside the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create sub folders or multiple controllers. Use a single controller **User Controller** which only contains entry points of each route. Move the business logic outside of the controller by creating a class or group of classes that take care of the process.

For example : You can create another directory **Libraries** under app folder and create a class **User** under Libraries which contains all functions of User resource.

app/Libraries/User.php

```
namespace App\Libraries;

class User {}
```

Now, you can access this class and functions using the namespace within your User Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Libraries\User;

class UserController extends Controller {}
```